# Aggregating more than two properties Java 8

Tags: lambda, java-8, sum, field, aggregate

To be very simple I have

```
 class Per{
    int a;
    long b;
    double c;
    String d;
}
```

Let say I have 3000 Object of Type `Per` and collected in a `List<Per> pers`

Now I want to achieve:-

- Skip if object is null or `d` is `null` or `blank`
- sum of `a`
- sum of `b`
- aggregated value of operation performed on `c`

> Old way is

```
int totalA = 0; long totalB = 0l; long totalC = 0l;
    for (Per per : pers) {
        if (per.d != null && !per.d.trim().equals("")) {
            totalA += per.a;
            totalB += per.b;
            totalC += someOperation(per.c);
        }
    }
```

`someOperation` implemention is not important as it may be simple or complex.

> How can I achieve this via Java8 streams and lambda expression?

A possible answer would be like this

```
int totalA = 0; long totalB=0l;
     pers.stream().filter(p->{
         if(p == null || p.d == null || p.d.trim().equals(""))
             return false;
         return true;
     }).forEach(per->{
         totalA += per.a;
            totalB += per.b;
     });
```

**But totalA and totalB  must be final or effectively final**

Other possibilities in my mind are:

1 re-use the filtered stream using `Supplier` as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36263725/3522181) then apply map and aggregation operations.

2 Collect the filtered `Per` and then do forEach

**NOTE I'm not doing any kind of grouping here and can't create new `Per` or update provided objects.**

Comment: what is the reason you cant create a new Per object? Because if you could, the `reduce` method could be really useful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write your own `Accumulator` class and a custom `Collector`, then it's a simple task.

```
class Accumulator {
  private int a = 0;
  private long b = 0L;
  private double c = 0d;

  public void accumulate(Per p) {
    a += p.a;
    b += p.b;
    c += someOperation(p.c);
  }

  public Accumulator combine(Accumulator acc) {
    a += acc.a;
    b += acc.b;
    c += acc.c;
    return this;
  }
  // getter, hashCode, ...
}
```

---

```
Accumulator result = pers.stream()
    .filter(p -> p != null && p.d != null && !p.d.trim().isEmpty())
    .collect(Collector.of(Accumulator::new, Accumulator::accumulate, Accumulator::combine));
```

Comment: There is a way to use `Predicate` in filter: `((Predicate<Per>) Objects::nonNull).and(per -> Objects.nonNull(per.d).and(p -> p.d.trim().isEmpty()))`

Comment: @AntonBalaniuc You're right, but writing `p != null` is more concise than target type casting.