# Java Stream group by 02 fields and aggregate by sum on 2 BigDecimal fields

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Need help for a case on Stream with groupingBy
I would like to be able to group by 2 different fields and have the sum of other BigDecimal fields, according to the different groupings. Here is my entity :

```
    public class Customer {
        private String name;
        private String type;
        private BigDecimal total;
        private BigDecimal balance;

// Setter, getter

}
```

Let's suppose I have as input this list:

```
Customer custa = new Customer("A", "STANDARD", new BigDecimal("1000"), new BigDecimal("1500"));
    Customer custa1 = new Customer("A", "VIP", new BigDecimal("2000"), new BigDecimal("2500"));
    Customer custb = new Customer("B", "STANDARD", new BigDecimal("3000"), new BigDecimal("3500"));
    Customer custc = new Customer("C", "STANDARD", new BigDecimal("4000"), new BigDecimal("4500"));
    Customer custa2 = new Customer("A", "VIP", new BigDecimal("1500"), new BigDecimal("2500"));
    List<Customer> listCust = new ArrayList<>();
    listCust.add(custa);
    listCust.add(custa1);
    listCust.add(custb);
    listCust.add(custc);
    listCust.add(custa2);
```

The result should be

```
[
    {"A", "STANDARD", new BigDecimal("1000"), new BigDecimal("1500")},
    {"A", "VIP", new BigDecimal("3500"), new BigDecimal("5000")},
    {"B", "STANDARD", new BigDecimal("3000"), new BigDecimal("3500")},
    {"C", "STANDARD", new BigDecimal("4000"), new BigDecimal("4500")}
]
```

I have a beginning of solution, below, but I block at the moment of adding a second aggregation to sum up the balance:

```
listCust.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Customer::getName
                    , Collectors.groupingBy(Customer::getType
                        , Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO,Customer::getTotal,BigDecimal::add)))
                )
                .entrySet()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using [toMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-) using the merge function, stream the customer list and collect them into Map using `name-type` as key, and use the merge function, to sum up the `total` and `balance` for customers having same key

```
Collection<Customer> result = listCust.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(cu -> cu.getName() + "-" + cu.getType(),
                    Function.identity(), (c1, c2) -> {
                        c1.setTotal(c1.getTotal().add(c2.getTotal()));
                        c1.setBalance(c1.getBalance().add(c2.getBalance()));
                        return c1;
                    })).values();
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip toMap, exactly what I was missing

Answer (score 2):

```
Collection<Customer> customers = listCust.stream()
                                         .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                                 customer -> customer.getName() + '-' + customer.getType(),
                                                 Function.identity(), (one, two) -> {
                                                     String name = one.getName();
                                                     String type = one.getType();
                                                     BigDecimal total = one.getTotal().add(two.getTotal());
                                                     BigDecimal balance = one.getBalance().add(two.getBalance());
                                                     return new Customer(name, type, total, balance);
                                                 })).values();
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using string conncatenation for the intermediate hashmap that provides more flexibility could be to use an `Entry`. This would allow you to change your grouping types and handles the case of null values if you wrap the key or value in `Optional.ofNullable`. It does have the drawback of limiting you to only two elements to group by.

```
Customer custa = new Customer("A", "STANDARD", new BigDecimal("1000"), new BigDecimal("1500"));
Customer custa1 = new Customer("A", "VIP", new BigDecimal("2000"), new BigDecimal("2500"));
Customer custb = new Customer("B", "STANDARD", new BigDecimal("3000"), new BigDecimal("3500"));
Customer custc = new Customer("C", "STANDARD", new BigDecimal("4000"), new BigDecimal("4500"));
Customer custa2 = new Customer("A", "VIP", new BigDecimal("1500"), new BigDecimal("2500"));
Customer custa3 = new Customer(null, "VIP", new BigDecimal("1500"), new BigDecimal("2500"));
List<Customer> listCust = new ArrayList<>();
listCust.add(custa);
listCust.add(custa1);
listCust.add(custb);
listCust.add(custc);
listCust.add(custa2);
listCust.add(custa3);
Collection<Customer> result =  listCust.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                c -> Map.entry(Optional.ofNullable(c.getName()), c.getType()),
                Function.identity(),
                (c1, c2) -> new Customer(c1.getName(),
                        c1.getType(),
                        c1.getTotal().add(c2.getTotal()),
                        c1.getBalance().add(c2.getBalance()))))
        .values();
System.out.println(result);
```

outupt (inserted newlines for readability)

```
[
    Customer{name='null', type='VIP', total=1500, balance=2500},
    Customer{name='B', type='STANDARD', total=3000, balance=3500},
    Customer{name='C', type='STANDARD', total=4000, balance=4500},
    Customer{name='A', type='VIP', total=3500, balance=5000},
    Customer{name='A', type='STANDARD', total=1000, balance=1500}
]
```

Comment: Indeed @Jimbo , it is an alternative.
Nevertheless, note that Map.entry() is available from Java 9 and returns an NPE if the key or value is null.
I would update the code like this:
    ....
                c -> Map.entry(Optional.ofNullable(c.getName()), Optional.ofNullable(c.getType())),