# How to use Intstream and map method

Tags: java, java-stream

I have solved the problems from the Java book, and I have some questions.

In the code below, I want to create a new stream by doubling each element using the map intermediate operation. And I want to print a new stream to get the sum of all the elements except the number less than 50 in the generated stream.

How can i solve this ??

```
    package test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class tt {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Stream <String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\wonheelee\\eclipse-workspace\\test\\stream-data.txt"));


        IntStream IS = lines.mapToInt(Integer::valueOf);

        IS.forEach(System.out::println);
        lines.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
       // No action 
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go..

```
int result = lines
            .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
            .map(element -> element * 2) //Double
            .filter(element -> element >= 50) //Filter out values less than 50
            .sum(); //sum
```

You can combine the `mapToInt` and `map` in one `mapToInt` itself

```
.mapToInt(element -> Integer.parseInt(element) * 2)
```

Also, note as Aomine@ mentioned in the comments, using `Integer.parseInt` to avoid an extra boxing/unboxing.

---

I'm not quite sure what you mean by *create a new stream*. You can get a new Stream by calling `Files.lines` again.

You cannot reuse a Stream once it is already consumed.

Reference:

[Is there any way to reuse a Stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36255007/is-there-any-way-to-reuse-a-stream/36255069)

Comment: Just for better readabilty I would first run the `filter` and then the mapping function to double the integer in question.

Comment: @Aris you can't filter them without doubling it. anyhow i'd change `.mapToInt(Integer::valueOf)` to `.mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)` to avoid boxing and unboxing the value.

Comment: Of course you can do that. You need to first map them to an int `mapToInt` filter the mapped and transformed integer and then map that again using a doubling action, before finally applying the `sum` terminal operation.

Comment: @Aris unless I am missing something, the only case where you can `filter` first then `map` and still suffice is `lines
                    .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                    .filter(a -> a * 2 >= 50)
                    .map(a -> a * 2) 
                    .sum();` which is not what you're saying.  but i'd avoid that and just do `ines.mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)  
               .map(i -> i * 2).filter(i -> i >= 50)         
               .sum();`

Comment: @Aomine that is exactly what I'm referring to (the last line of code).

Comment: @Aris My understanding is that the OP wants to double first and then filter. If you filter first, then you won't get number say for ex, 26.

Comment: @Aomine it's very trivial but I understood that they first want to map and filter and then apply the doubling action.

Comment: @Aomine for the smart people: `.mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).filter(a -> a >= 25).sum()*2` ;-)

Comment: @Holger oh my..... that's too smart! , no many people would think of that approach.

Comment: @Holger I have to admit, I had to _double_ check this on [ideone](https://ideone.com/T9Gbi7) to make sure what my brain is processing is correct.

Comment: @Holger Nice one

Comment: @Aomine It is - `2*a + 2*b + 2*c ..` which is `2 * (a + b + c)`