# Java streams: flatMap returns Stream of Objects

Tags: java, java-stream

I've this code:

```
List<Application> applications = this.applicationDao.findAll();
Collection<Pair<Application, FileObject>> files = applications.stream()
    .flatMap(app -> streamOfFiles.map(file -> Pair.of(app, file)));
```

where `streamOfFiles` is an `Stream<FileObject>`

Currently, I'm getting this compilation message:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from `Stream<Object>` to `Collection<Pair<Application,FileObject>>`

Any ideas?

Comment: flatMap() is not terminal operation. You should call any terminal operation if you want to return result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be missing the `collect` there :

```
Collection<Pair<Application, FileObject>> files = applications.stream()
        .flatMap(app -> files.stream().map(file -> Pair.of(app, file)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList()); // any collection you want
```

***Edit***: Since, `streamOfFiles` is getting consumed at a single `flatMap` operation, you should prefer to use a `<collection>.stream()` instead there to create the stream afresh for each `app`.

Answer (score 3):

You can't reuse [streamOfFiles](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36255007/4796021) Stream while iterating over `applications`!

You need to transform `streamOfFiles` from a `Stream<FileObject>` to `List<FileObject>` and then:

```
List<FileObject> listOfFiles = streamOfFiles.collect(Collectors.toList());
List<Application> applications = this.applicationDao.findAll();
Collection<Pair<Application, FileObject>> files =  applications.stream()
            .flatMap(app -> listOfFiles.stream().map(file -> Pair.of(app, file)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

A simple example to prove that:

```
Stream<Integer> s = IntStream.range(0, 100).boxed();
IntStream.range(0, 100).boxed()
         .flatMap(i -> s.map(j -> i * j))
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It throws this Exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed

Comment: You're right. Its called for each `Application` and that is where it is getting *operated upon.* and hence the error. `<collection>.stream` should be a better approach here.