# Is it possible to collect a stream into two collectors

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I have a list of strings on which i want to want to write the distinct set of strings in a file as well as convert it to UUIDs and store it another variable.
Is it possible with Java 8 lambdas and how?

The reason i asked for two collectors is to avoid running it into a second loop.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30211021/2711488) is helpful.

Comment: Interesting problem, however it sounds to me like unnecessary optimisation, which will give insignificant performance improvement (given that you are writing to files) and drastically reduce the readability and maintainability of the code.

Comment: Let's not consider significance of performance implications and just talk about if and how it is possible...Maybe not in this case, but performance improvement will not be insignificant if there are two costly collector operations...Also, readability is subjective. Some might say lambdas are not readable/maintainable.

Answer (score 3):

This is possible in [Java 12](https://jdk.java.net/12/) which introduced `Collectors.teeing`:

```
public static <T, R1, R2, R>
Collector<T, ?, R> teeing(Collector<? super T, ?, R1> downstream1,
                          Collector<? super T, ?, R2> downstream2,
                          BiFunction<? super R1, ? super R2, R> merger);
```

> Returns a Collector that is a composite of two downstream collectors. Every element passed to the resulting collector is processed by both downstream collectors, then their results are merged using the specified merge function into the final result.

Example:

```
Entry<Long, Long> entry = Stream
        .of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
        .collect(teeing(
                filtering(i -> i % 2 != 0, counting()),
                counting(),
                Map::entry));

System.out.println("Odd count: " + entry.getKey());
System.out.println("Total count: " + entry.getValue());
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Holger noted I wrote a [pairing collector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30211021/4856258) as an answer to another question which aggregates two collectors. Such collector is readily available now in my [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library: [`MoreCollectors.pairing`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/javax/util/streamex/MoreCollectors.html#pairing-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.function.BiFunction-). Similar collector is [available](http://www.jooq.org/products/jOO%CE%BB/javadoc/0.9.5/org/jooq/lambda/tuple/Tuple.html#collectors-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.stream.Collector-) in jOOL library as well.

Comment: So are you saying nothing is available out of the box on Java 8 lambdas for such a situation.

Comment: @Mulki, yes, no ready solution to combine two collectors exists. Well, you can simply do everything inside the single `forEach()` with side-effects.