# Feed into map and list parallely from single list

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a list like following.

```
List<Model> models = ....
```

Until now, I was doing like this

```
List<String> anotherlist = models.parallelStream().map(Model::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Now, I created another map

```
Map<String, Model> modelsMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Model>();
for (final Model model : models) {
   modelsMap.put(model.getId(), model);
}
```

Is it possible when I create do parallel stream on `models` list , I can prepare my `modelsMap` also side by side without have to traverse the `models` list again? Is parallel stream only bound to one kind of operation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java 8 List<V> into Map<K, V>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363719/java-8-listv-into-mapk-v)

Answer (score 5):

It seems what you want is just:

```
ConcurrentMap<String, Model> modelsMap = 
        models.parallelStream()
              .collect(toConcurrentMap(Model::getId, identity()));
```

This creates a `ConcurrentMap` from the list of models by collecting it with [`Collectors.toConcurrentMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toConcurrentMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-). The key mapper is the function that returns the name of the model and the value mapper is the identity function.

Note that this will throws an exception is case of duplicate ids.

If you want to create the list of names along with this Map in the same Stream pipeline, you could use the [`pairing`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30211021/1743880) collector written in this answer and hold the result inside a custom `Pair` class. The Map will be the first element of the pair and the list of names will be the second.

```
Pair<Map<String, Model>, List<String>> pair = 
        models.parallelStream()
              .collect(pairing(
                    toConcurrentMap(Model::getId, identity()),
                    mapping(Model::getName, toList()),
                    Pair::new)
              );

static <T, A1, A2, R1, R2, R> Collector<T, ?, R> pairing(Collector<T, A1, R1> c1, 
        Collector<T, A2, R2> c2, BiFunction<R1, R2, R> finisher) {
    EnumSet<Characteristics> c = EnumSet.noneOf(Characteristics.class);
    c.addAll(c1.characteristics());
    c.retainAll(c2.characteristics());
    c.remove(Characteristics.IDENTITY_FINISH);
    return Collector.of(() -> new Object[] {c1.supplier().get(), c2.supplier().get()},
            (acc, v) -> {
                c1.accumulator().accept((A1)acc[0], v);
                c2.accumulator().accept((A2)acc[1], v);
            },
            (acc1, acc2) -> {
                acc1[0] = c1.combiner().apply((A1)acc1[0], (A1)acc2[0]);
                acc1[1] = c2.combiner().apply((A2)acc1[1], (A2)acc2[1]);
                return acc1;
            },
            acc -> {
                R1 r1 = c1.finisher().apply((A1)acc[0]);
                R2 r2 = c2.finisher().apply((A2)acc[1]);
                return finisher.apply(r1, r2);
            }, c.toArray(new Characteristics[c.size()]));
}
```

with the following `Pair` class:

```
public class Pair<T, U> {
    private final T first;
    private final U second;

    public Pair(T first, U second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    public T getFirst() {
        return first;
    }
    public U getSecond() {
        return second;
    }
}
```

Comment: but here i have to traverse again the list. right ? i want in single traversal of models list generate otherslist and modelsmap.

Comment: Then you have to write your own `Collector`!

Comment: @SaurabhKumar, Tunaki edited the answer, so you can see the single traversal solution. Though I doubt that you will really gain some performance on it.

Comment: @SaurabhKumar The code looks more complicated but that's because (unfortunately), there is no built-in collector in the API that combines multiple collectors and there is no built-in pair class (although you could (abuse) `Map.Entry` but I'd rather not to).

Comment: @Tunaki : Thanks for your answer. It was very good to know something like this is also possible. Just for the project sake i will go for old school forEach loop since will b easier for other developers to understand well.