# Is it possible to collect a stream to two different collections using one line?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have the following code: (simplified for bravity)

```
public void search(Predicate<String> predicate, Elements elements)
{
    List<SearchResult> searchResults = elements.stream()
        .filter(element -> predicate.test(element.ownText()))
        .map(element -> new SearchResult(element.ownText(), element.baseUri(),element.tagName()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

But now, I want to have another list which would contain all filtered elements without the mapping.
Is it possible to do that with a stream, or should I change to a foreach loop for that?

Comment: You could do it with a custom collector. But another solution would be to have 2 Stream pipeline.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can collect the elements after filtering and then use this list to map the elements to search results:

```
public void search(Predicate<String> predicate, Elements elements) {
    List<Element> filteredElements = 
        elements.stream()
                .filter(element -> predicate.test(element.ownText()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

    List<SearchResult> searchResults = 
        filteredElements.stream()
                        .map(element -> new SearchResult(element.ownText(),element.baseUri(),element.tagName()))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

This won't take more time than the solutions of the other answers but doesn't have side effects, is thread safe as well as easy to read and understand.

Answer (score 5):

A simple way to do this would be

```
List<Element> filteredElements = new ArrayList<>();
List<SearchResult> searchResults = elements.stream()
      .filter(element -> predicate.test(element.ownText()))
      .peek(filteredElements::add)
      .map(element -> 
         new SearchResult(element.ownText(),element.baseUri(),element.tagName()))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Nice and elegant! Thank you.

Comment: This use of peek gives me a very bad feeling, although I cannot state anything specific that is wrong with it. It feels like an abuse of peek.

Comment: @DavidConrad because from the [`peek` Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-): “_This method exists mainly to support debugging, where you want to see the elements as they flow past a certain point in a pipeline_”.

Comment: @DavidConrad your senses are probably tingling because `peek(filteredElements::add)` introduces a side effect (adding elements to `filteredElements`). Also, when `elements.stream()` returns a parallel stream, `filteredElements` may not contain all filtered elements as ArrayList is not thread safe.

Comment: @Acanda Good call. It didn't take much to get `ArrayList` to break. A straightforward parallel use results in either missing elements or an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. A `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` avoids that problem, though I'm still not thrilled with this usage.

Comment: @DavidConrad I added an answer with a solution that's both thread safe and without side effects.

Answer (score 2):

One alternative is to define a `Supplier<Stream>`:

```
public void search(Predicate<String> predicate, Elements elements)
{
    Supplier<Stream<Element>> supplier = () -> elements.stream()
           .filter(element -> predicate.test(element.ownText()));
    List<SearchResult> searchResults = supplier.get()
           .map(element -> new SearchResult(element.ownText(),element.baseUri(),element.tagName()))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<Element> elementList = supplier.get().collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Note that using this approach you actually perform the filtering twice.

An alternative (though not very beautiful in this case) solution is use `pairing` collector from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30211021/4856258):

```
Collector<Element, ?, List<SearchResult>> c1 = 
    Collectors.mapping(element -> new SearchResult(element.ownText(),element.baseUri(),element.tagName()),
        Collectors.toList());
Collector<Element, ?, List<Element>> c2 = Collectors.toList();
Collector<Element, ?, Pair<List<SearchResult>, List<Element>>> pairCollector =
    pairing(c1, c2, Pair::new); // Assumes some Pair class existing

Pair<List<SearchResult>, List<Element>> result = elements.stream()
           .filter(element -> predicate.test(element.ownText()))
           .collect(pairing);
```

These solutions are generic: they allow to do two different operations with single data source. But in your concrete example it's easier to create first list of filtered non-mapped data, then create a second stream on that list:

```
List<Element> elementList = elements.stream()
           .filter(element -> predicate.test(element.ownText()))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
List<SearchResult> searchResults = elementList.stream()
           .map(element -> new SearchResult(element.ownText(),element.baseUri(),element.tagName()))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I think the last approach is the best in this case. However there are actually 3 very different answers here, maybe worth splitting them?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the stream twice, as it is closed when using collect. **The following code will throw an "java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed"**. So you need to create the stream twice or use a for-each loop.

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

class Test
{
    static class SearchResult
    {
        SearchResult(Object o,Object p,Object q) {}
    }

    static class Element
    {
        public String ownText() {return "text";}
        public String tagName() {return "tag";}
        public String baseUri() {return "base";}
    }

    public static void search(Predicate<String> predicate, List<Element> elements)
    {
        Stream<Element> stream = elements.stream().filter(element -> predicate.test(element.ownText()));
        List<Element> filtered = stream.collect(Collectors.toList());
        // next line will throw the IllegalStateException as above line has already consumed the stream
        List<SearchResult> results =    stream.map(element -> 
         new SearchResult(element.ownText(),element.baseUri(),element.tagName()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {       
        search(s->true,Collections.singletonList(new Element()));
    }
}
```