# How to collect two sum from a stream in Java 8

Tags: java, java-stream

```
class Stock{
   double profit;
   double profitPercentage;
   public double getProfit(){
      return profit;
   }
   public double getProfitPercentage(){
      return profitPercentage;
   }
}
List<Stock> stocks = getAllStocks();
stocks.stream.collect(Collectors.summarizingDouble(Stock:getProfit)).getSum();
stocks.stream.collect(Collectors.summarizingDouble(Stock:getProfitPercentage)).getSum();
```

I could not find out way to do in single pass of stream. Any help or pointer would be good.

Comment: You're looking for something [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30211021/1743880).

Comment: The link was showing something like groupby and sum. For me, I require to execute sum of 2 fields and no group by.

Comment: Do you sum of all profits and profit percentages?

Comment: Yes, exactly, sum of all profits and sum of all profitpercentages

Comment: Just write your own collector instead of using `Collectors.summarizingDouble`. The return type would not be a single double value, but a POJO or Tuple2 that contains both sums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The straight-forward way is to create a custom collector class.

```
public class StockStatistics {

    private DoubleSummaryStatistics profitStat = new DoubleSummaryStatistics();
    private DoubleSummaryStatistics profitPercentageStat = new DoubleSummaryStatistics();

    public void accept(Stock stock) {
        profitStat.accept(stock.getProfit());
        profitPercentageStat.accept(stock.getProfitPercentage());
    }

    public StockStatistics combine(StockStatistics other) {
        profitStat.combine(other.profitStat);
        profitPercentageStat.combine(other.profitPercentageStat);
        return this;
    }

    public static Collector<Stock, ?, StockStatistics> collector() {
        return Collector.of(StockStatistics::new, StockStatistics::accept, StockStatistics::combine);
    }

    public DoubleSummaryStatistics getProfitStat() {
        return profitStat;
    }

    public DoubleSummaryStatistics getProfitPercentageStat() {
        return profitPercentageStat;
    }

}
```

This class serves as a wrapper around two `DoubleSummaryStatistics`. It delegates to them each time an element is accepted. In your case, since you're only interested in the sum, you could even use a `Collectors.summingDouble` instead of `DoubleSummaryStatistics`. Also, it returns the two statistics with `getProfitStat` and `getProfitPercentageStat`; alternatively, you could add a finisher operation that would return a `double[]` containing only both sums.

Then, you can use

```
StockStatistics stats = stocks.stream().collect(StockStatistics.collector());
System.out.println(stats.getProfitStat().getSum());
System.out.println(stats.getProfitPercentageStat().getSum());
```

---

A more generic way is to create a collector capable of pairing other collectors. You can use the `pairing` collector written [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30211021/1743880) and, also available [in the StreamEx library](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/MoreCollectors.html#pairing-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.function.BiFunction-).

```
double[] sums = stocks.stream().collect(MoreCollectors.pairing(
    Collectors.summingDouble(Stock::getProfit),
    Collectors.summingDouble(Stock::getProfitPercentage),
    (sum1, sum2) -> new double[] { sum1, sum2 }
));
```

The sum of the profit will be in `sums[0]` and the sum of the profit percentage will be in `sums[1]`. In this snippet, only the sums are kept and not the whole stats.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use [`Collectors.teeing`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#teeing(java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.function.BiFunction)) available since Java 12:

```
double[] res =
    getAllStocks().stream()
        .collect(
            Collectors.teeing(
                Collectors.summingDouble(Stock::getProfit),
                Collectors.summingDouble(Stock::getProfitPercentage),
                (profitSum, percentageSum) -> new double[] {profitSum, percentageSum}));
```